# Have one plot as background for stacked plots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a series of plots that are stacked up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\tikzexternalize% activate externalization!
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[stack plots=y,
                   area style,
                   enlargelimits=false,
                   ymin=0,
                   ylabel = {\small time for million dof updates},
                   xlabel = {\small Order},
                   grid=major,
                   legend style={
                     at={(0.5,-0.10)},
                     anchor=north
                   },
                   width=15.0cm]
        \addplot[draw=cyan, fill=cyan] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{A}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat} \closedcycle;
        \addlegendentry{A}
        \addplot[draw=yellow, fill=yellow] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{B}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat} \closedcycle;
        \addlegendentry{B}
        \addplot[draw=gray, fill=gray] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{C}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat} \closedcycle;
        \addlegendentry{C}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In addition, I want to have one plot out of these not stacked up, but have it to be something like a background.

The easiest way to get something like this was to leave the stacked up area plots as they are and add the background plot using a line plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\tikzexternalize% activate externalization!
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[stack plots=y,
                   area style,
                   enlargelimits=false,
                   ymin=0,
                   ylabel = {\small time for million dof updates},
                   xlabel = {\small Order},
                   grid=major,
                   legend style={
                     at={(0.5,-0.10)},
                     anchor=north
                   },
                   width=15.0cm]
        \addplot[draw=cyan, fill=cyan] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{A}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat} \closedcycle;
        \addlegendentry{A}
        \addplot[draw=yellow, fill=yellow] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{B}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat} \closedcycle;
        \addlegendentry{B}
        \addplot[draw=gray, fill=gray] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{C}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat} \closedcycle;
        \addlegendentry{C}
        \addplot[draw=magenta, fill=magenta, line legend, thick, sharp plot, stack plots=false] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{D}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat};
        \addlegendentry{D}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But the plot appears still to be affected by the area style of the axis environment. Any idea how to have the last plot only as a simple line?

Another solution that comes to mind is to start a second axis and add the line there. But in this case it wouldn't be part of the first plot's legend. So this is also not applicable.

The data file should look like this:

```
 A  B  C   D  X    Y     Z
 7  1  1  11  8 1000  3072
11  3  2  18 27 1000 10368
14  2  5  24 64 1000 24576
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry for that. I have the code in seperate files and simply forgot to add the complete code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was already near the answer. The problem is in the line

```
\addplot[draw=magenta, fill=magenta, line legend, thick, sharp plot, stack plots=false] table[x expr=\thisrow{X}^0.33333333333, y expr=\thisrow{D}*10^6/(\thisrow{Y}*\thisrow{Z})]{data.dat};
```

where it says `fill=magenta`. Without the fill, it also plots just a line.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in your comment, you can use an additional axis environment (with the options `axis y line=none,axis x line=none`). And if you want this extra plot to appear within the first axis' legend, just add the corresponding entry by yourself, with something like :

```
\addlegendimage{magenta, thick} % Same style as the non-stacked plot
    \addlegendentry{entry for the non-stacked plot}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It also works, but changing my code to the one you suggested let me discover the mistake I made. Thank you anyway for your help.